# How to write a dataframe to hdfs csv in random order?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to write a dataframe to hdfs. But order by random is very slow although there are only 17 million data rows.

```
df = df.withColumn('random_index',rand())
df = df.orderBy('random_index')

df.write.csv('hdfs:///user/yananc/yanan_gbdt_dnn', sep=',')
```

Is there any fast and efficient way to realize this?

Comment: What do you mean by "very slow" ? How are you measuring that time ? What's your cluster configuration ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `orderBy` will sort the rows across all partitions of the dataframe. Since you are interested in only shuffling the rows, you could look into using `sortWithinPartitions` instead. No shuffling of data is required with this method, so it is faster:

```
df.sortWithinPartitions(rand())
```

Of course, depending on the dataframe, this will not give a totally random order on the data. This depends on how the rows are distributed across the partitions.